# Music lens does not show my music

Tags: unity, 12.10, music, rhythmbox, lenses

I have 10GBs of mp3, aac and flac files on my hard disk. Most of them were legally purchased online or ripped from CDs. Some of them aren't. The music lens does not show any of my music when I search. When I installed 12.10 I immediately removed Rhythmbox and installed Audacious. Is this the reason why this is happening?

Or does it work only for music from the Ubuntu Music Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a scope for the music lens for Audacious available in the Scopes Packagers PPA.  To install, enter the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-scope-audacious
```

Log out and log back in again to activate the scope.