# How to Tell Dash to look for music on other NTFS partitions?

Tags: 13.04, unity-dash, music, lenses

All my songs and videos are present in NTFS partition, as a result whenever i search for music in dash it results nothing. So how do i tell dash to look for content in specific folder rather than looking only in home folder.

Comment: is your NTFS partition mounted? Usually Ubuntu does not mount it by default, unless you specified to do so.

Comment: yes, all NTFS partitions are mounted. Iam using Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Press Super+M(Windows button +M) and search for a track you have it on your pc and wait a wile. Please tell me if it finds it or not.

Comment: done as you said, but search did not find that

Comment: 1 more question. Does your music file have the artist and the song name set? I am not sure but i think the music lens is searchng for those.

Answer (score 0):

Add your music to your player's library.

I think this question is very similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253781/music-lens-does-not-show-my-music).  The Unity music lens uses different Scopes - Banshee by default, I gather - to provide results.  This is part of the [lens spec](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses#Responsibilities_of_a_Scope).  Banshee ONLY provides music results that are inside its library, so anything else won't show up.

In any event, for ease-of-use, I'd recommend creating a symlink to your NTFS partition inside your music folder:
`ln -s /path/to/NTFS/music ~/Music/External`.  This way, Banshee'll see that music as existing inside your Music directory, as will any other player you use.

**Edit:** Just found a duplicate - [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60564/how-do-you-change-the-search-location-of-the-music-lens?rq=1).  Answers are quite similar.